# How to send the array of the checkbox values in Symfony

Tags: jquery, symfony

I seek how to send values for checkbox buttons that are checked by the user to my path "deleteAll" to remove them.

so I find the treatment that allows Declared all buttons when I click "selectAll". So there is the party of sending values to the route "deleteAll" in jQuery. I do not know how.

this is my test:

http://jsfiddle.net/ScnQT/2533/

Code In Html:

```
<form id ="deleteAll" method="post" action="{{path('deleteAll')}}" >
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll[]"/> Check all</label></p>

    <fieldset>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{ entity.id}}"/> Option 1</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{ entity.id}"/> Option 2</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="item"value="{{ entity.id}" /> Option 3</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{ entity.id}"/> Option 4</label></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Code Jquery:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#checkAll").click(function(){

            var checked_status = this.checked;

            $("input[name='check[]']").each(function(){

                this.checked = checked_status;
                var v = $("#d").val();

                $('#deleteAll').submit(function(){
                    $("#deleteAll").attr("action", "{{ path('projets_deleteAll') }}" + v);
                });
            });

        });
    });


</script>
```

thank you,

Comment: id is `checkAll[]` not `checkAll` in your markup

Comment: missing jQuery library in snippet   http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/ScnQT/2524/

Comment: You should [submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) the form with jQuery.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in the action of the form "<form action =" {{path ( 'deleteAll')}} ">" how will change according array ids and how to retrieve values for this example it is the selection only.

Answer (score 1):

For passing the parameters from your form to your controller use:

```
//in your deleteAllAction function
$params = $request->get()->all(); // to get all GET params
```

And to get every parameter from your form

```
$param1 = $request->get('name')['param1']; //name = the value of name attribute of one of your inputs (in your case)
$param2 = $request->get('name')['param2'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the information, I change my script to send ids but still does not work ;(

Comment: If you are just passing the values from your form by POST you don't need any script to do that. You only have to create your method: public function deleteAllAction(Request $request) {...} and in there put what I post in this answer. At least in this way was how I do this once.